# Erro Trying to get property of non-object ao tentar acessar pela view Blade no laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade

Estou tentando após um foreach acessar a variavel com o array de objetos na blade mas ele apresanta o erro Trying to get property of non-object.
Já tentei com o "firt" mas ele só pega o primeiro de casa laço na consulta, porem funciona, poderiam me ajudar?

```
    <?php 
         $artigo = 'short';

         $get_cat=  DB::table('products')
         ->where('category', '=', $artigo)
         ->select('id_product')
         ->get();
         
         ?>
  <div>
    <a href="#" data-open-in="picker" data-picker-close-text="OK" data-back-on-select="true" class="item-link smart-select" >
     <select  class="products_qto select-filter-size"  name="product" id="product-qto" >
        <option selected>TAM</option>
         -- @foreach ($get_cat as $key => $tam_prod)
         <?php
            $tam = DB::table('sizes')
              ->where('id_product', '=', $tam_prod->id_product)
              ->select('title')
              ->get();  
          ?>
        <option value="{{$tam->title}}">{{$tam->title}}</option>
   @endforeach   
    </select>                                                                                                         
   </a>
  </div>
    <a href="#" onclick="cancelSearchProducts()">LIMPAR</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tem alguns pontos nesse seu código que não estão muito bons, e talvez impactando para esse seu problema.
Aconselho dar uma estudada em relations e fazer essas informações virem da controller.

Mas sobre o erro:
O erro em si diz que não existe uma das propriedades nesse objeto que tu ta tentando iterar, e se com o `first()` está funcionando significa que a collection que está sendo atribuída na sua variável $tam está trazendo outro array de objetos, você precisa iterar ele também fazendo assim um segundo loop:

```
    <?php 
         $artigo = 'short';

         $get_cat=  DB::table('products')
         ->where('category', '=', $artigo)
         ->select('id_product')
         ->get();
         
         ?>
  <div>
    <a href="#" data-open-in="picker" data-picker-close-text="OK" data-back-on-select="true" class="item-link smart-select" >
     <select  class="products_qto select-filter-size"  name="product" id="product-qto" >
        <option selected>TAM</option>
         @foreach ($get_cat as $key => $tam_prod)
         <?php
            $tam = DB::table('sizes')
              ->where('id_product', '=', $tam_prod->id_product)
              ->select('title')
              ->get();  
          ?>
        @foreach ($tam as $tam_item)
          <option value="{{$tam_item->title}}">{{$tam_item->title}}</option>
        @endforeach   
   @endforeach   
    </select>                                                                                                         
   </a>
  </div>
    <a href="#" onclick="cancelSearchProducts()">LIMPAR</a>
</div>
```

Mas lembrando esse jeito não é aconselhado, tu poderia criar uma relation de produtos e sizes, facilitaria muito e não ficaria tão estranho ter q fazer esses 2 foreach e 2 querys só pra trazer a lista de tamanho dos produtos.

Comment: Opa, tudo bem?
Sei que o codigo esta bem bagunçado, mas o sistema não foi desenvolvido por min, estou só fazendo uns ajustes para um cliente. O dev que desenvolveu abandou o projeto antes de fazer controllers e a grana que estão pagando, por enquanto, não inclui esse trampo nem relacionar a tabela no BD, só uma alteção msm, mas muito obrigado pela resposta!

Comment: Sobre a solução, com o get o &tam esta realmente com um array de arrays, que ele constroi a cada volta no laço, deu certo aqui 
Muito obrigado!

Comment: De nada é nois.